# LUA load JSON configuration from file

Tags: json, nginx, lua, openresty, cjson

I'm trying to move old LUA method which was loading some JSON content from file into global variable into "class". But I get following errors all the time:

```
attempt to call field 'decode' (a nil value)
attempt to index global 'cjson' (a nil value)
```

I don't know lua well but i tried almost all combinations without result so can you explain why this errors occurs?

Current implementation of module looks like:

```
Config = {}
Config.__index = Config

function Config.create(config_filename)
   local cjson = require("cjson") 
   local config = {}               
   setmetatable(config,Config)  

   local f = io.open(config_filename, "r")
   local content = f:read("*a")
   f:close()
   config = cjson.decode(content)

   return config
end

return Config
```

As final result I want to execute something like this from other file:

```
local config_class = require("config")
local config = config_class.create("/path/to/file.json")

ngx.say(config:some_configuration_data())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you cjson and decode are nil values which cannot be indexed or called.

`require` will load some file and run the contained code and pass the return value through. If you run a Lua script it behaves like a function which returns `nil` by default. So unless you specify what the script returns `require` will return `nil`.

I don't know what is inside your cjson file that you require but it obviously does not return the wanted json implementation but `nil`.

So the code in cjson should return a Lua table with a function stored under key "decode".

Comment: And how how can I force require to load proper "cjson" implementation?

Comment: Ok I messed up with load path. It seems to work after load path fixes. Thanks.